# check box value to be true when loading the data table in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am working with a data table and one of my columns is a check box.

when populating the data table below I am trying to have all of the Accept checkboxes selected by default
[image]

when loading the data to be displayed I have tried the following different options below but none of them had success

```
Using BatchHead As DataTable = _SQL.GetDBDataTableSimple(SQLString)
                If Not BatchHead Is Nothing Then
                    For iI = 0 To BatchHead.Rows.Count - 1
                        If _StopLoading Then Exit Sub
                        With TheGridView
                            .Rows.Add()
                            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(0).Value = BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("THEID")
                            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(1).Value = BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("BatchCode")
                            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(2).Value = Format(CDate(BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("TransDate")), "dd/MM/yyyy")
                            If BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("Printed") = "Y" Then .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(3).Value = Format(CDate(BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("PrintedDate")), "dd/MM/yyyy")
                            If BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("Released") = "Y" Then .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(4).Value = Format(CDate(BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("ReleasedDate")), "dd/MM/yyyy")
                            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(5).Value = BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("UserCreated")
                            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(6).Value = NullLng(BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("TheCount"))


'-------------------------------------
I have tried the following combination
                            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = TheGridView.CurrentCell.Selected
                            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = True
                            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = Accept.TrueValue
                            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = Accept.FalseValue

'-------------------------------------

                            If BatchType = BatchTypes.PromotionSimple Then
                                If BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("Status") = "AL" Then
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green
                                    '.Rows(.RowCount - 1).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = "AL"
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(8).Value = "NO"
                                ElseIf BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("Status") = "AF" Then
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green
                                    '.Rows(.RowCount - 1).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = "AF"
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(8).Value = "YES"
                                ElseIf BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("Status") = "OF" Then
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = "OF"
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(8).Value = "YES"
                                ElseIf BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("Status") = "CO" Then
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = "OF"
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(8).Value = "YES"
                                Else
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = ""
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(8).Value = "NO"
                                End If
                                
                                If (Not CBool(setting.some_setting) Then
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(9).Value = selectedBatches.Contains(.Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(0).Value)
                                End If
                            ElseIf BatchType = BatchTypes.Promotion Then
                                If BatchHead.Rows(iI).Item("Status") = "OF" Then
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = "OF"
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(8).Value = "YES"
                                Else
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = ""
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(8).Value = "NO"
                                End If
                                
                                If (Not CBool(setting.some_setting)) Then
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(9).Value = selectedBatches.Contains(.Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(0).Value)
                                End If
                            Else
                                
                                If (Not CBool(setting.some_setting)) Then
                                    .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = selectedBatches.Contains(.Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(0).Value)
                                End If
                            End If
                            Application.DoEvents()
                        End With
                    Next
                End If
            End Using
```

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Modify the datasource directly.  The column in your datatable should be boolean, so set True for Checked and False for Unchecked.  Set the datatable as the DataSource of your BindingSource then set the BindingSource as the Datasource to the DataGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(7).Value = True

the above worked perfectly for me, I didn't realize that my value was being overwritten in the If (Not CBool(setting.some_setting)) statement.

thank you for the support.